# I want to create a video of same resolution as of image

Tags: sound, video, php, display-resolution, ffmpeg

I am able to create a video from image and audio.I am using a single image.The problem is that as i crop the image and creates video again then image pixels get burst in that video.

I am using this command -

```
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i 'image.jpeg' -i 'audio.mp3' -vf 
scale=1920*1080,fps=fps=30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -shortest 'out.mp4'
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: Please show the complete log from the ffmpeg command. It will help me understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the scale filter if you want the video to be the same resolution as the input:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -i image.jpeg -i audio.mp3 -vf format=yuv420p -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: @MukulKashyap `34i-1612351003.jpeg` looks bad so the video will look bad. `34i-1612351003.jpeg` looks like a different image than what is shown in the video `34i-1612351493.mp4`. I am unsure of the relationship of these files.